# How make an inner join with these models?

Tags: python, django

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField()
class City(models.Model):
    c = models.ForeignKey(Country)
class People(models.Model):
    c = models.ForeignKey(City)
```

I want all the Persons that belong to all the Cities belonging to the Country name="Cuba"

Comment: What does the second part of that mean? How can a B be "equal to A = 1"?

Comment: I've fixed your code indentation, but I don't know what you're asking either.. Perhaps some example data will be illuminating..?

Comment: I guess he wants something like: C.objects.filter(b__c=1). But I agree that question need to be improved to be more specific.

Comment: something like People.objects.filter(c__c__name='Cuba') but that's super heavy for the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Django's ORM you can do this fairly simple:

```
People.objects.filter(c__c__name='Cuba')
```

This will make two joins - first by `city` table and the second by `country`.
Look at [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).